# jquery hide/show function

Tags: jquery, centering

Hi! I'm just a newbie for `jquery` functions, I was able to finish the hide/show       function of certain divs but I want to make in centered way while executing the show   div.. Now these div has a content but when I click the show it appears from left to   right.. Can somebody do these trick to be centered?

```
window.onload = function(){
    $('#show').click(function()
    {
        $('#nav').show('blind');
        $('#show').hide();
        $('#hide').show();
    });

    $('#hide').click(function()
    {
        $('#nav').hide('blind');
        $('#hide').hide();
        $('#show').show();
    });
}
```

Comment: please provide the HTML and CSS code

Answer (score 1):

use .toggle()  for doing both hide and show in  a same time.u no need to write show and hide function separately

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p { background:#dad;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:16px; }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Toggle 'em</button>
<p>Hiya</p>
<p>Such interesting text, eh?</p>
<script>
$("button").click(function () {
$("p").toggle("slow");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i see thanks,, but what i was wondering if it is possible to get the presentation for example in center(from reference hidden to show state of that),,instead of executing from left to right upon clicking the toggle button?.

Comment: if u want popup from center like presentation see this link http://jqueryui.com/toggle/